# Unable to enter correct characters in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to start developing apps using IntelliJ IDE. I have downloaded and installed it with no problem.

Now, IntelliJ does the following when I enter on the keyboard:

- ; : button = $
- ctrl + shift = ^
- shift + "\' = @
- , button = ?
- . button = /

As a coder I will need a . (dot) and/or semicolon, in which IntelliJ does not respond correctly to what I am typing.

Comment: I don't get your exact problem. What are you typing, and what happens then? And in which window/view/... are?

Comment: I am unable to type/enter a dot or semicolon

Comment: @666DESH666 What OS and what keyboard layout do you use? Did you install any plug-ins?

Comment: I am using Windows OS -- And no plugins were installed for IntelliJ

Comment: Do you use an english QWERTY keyboard layout or something else?